# samba share giving group permissions

Tags: samba

I've read the documentation for samba share. They say I have to use @groupname to give a group to access the share. Like this:

```
valid users = @groupname
```

I'm not sure, but I've read somewhere +groupname is also possible to use to give a group to access the share. Like this:

```
valid users = +groupname
```

Both of them are correct?

Answer (score 0):

On the [Samba.org site](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html) they are showing that for the group name you do it with the `@` like shown below:

```
[accounting]
    comment = Accounting Department Directory
    writable = yes
    valid users = @account
    path = /home/samba/accounting
    create mode = 0660
    directory mode = 0770
```

Hope this helps!